# How do I use jquery so that when one tile is pressed the others revert back to their natural state

Tags: jquery, html

I have five tiles in a row. When a tile is pressed it is given a box shadow. However if tile 1 has been pressed when tile 2 is pressed, I need tile 1 to lose the box shadow. I am hopping to use jquery to accomplish this. What do I need to change about my code to achieve this goal? Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="fltsqrs" id="fltsqrs1"><img src="../images/cash flow.png" alt=" "><p>Treasury Services</p></div>
    <div class="fltsqrs" id="fltsqrs2"><img src="../images/taxes2.png"><p>Taxes</p></div>
    <div class="fltsqrs"><img src="../images/Team.png" alt=" "><p>Bookkeeping</p></div>
    <div class="fltsqrs"><img src="../images/strategy.png" alt=" "><p>Planning</p></div>
    <div class="fltsqrs"><img src="../images/1449867816_1.png" alt=" "><p>HR Services</p></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fltsqrs').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("fltsqrs2");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.fltsqrs {
    float:left;
    height:175px;
    width:185px;
    background-color:white;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:35px;
    border-radius:30px;
}

.fltsqrs2 {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply toggle the other tiles off before adding the `fltsqrs2` class to the one your just clicked. You can do that with `removeClass`, like this.

```
$('.fltsqrs').removeClass("fltsqrs2");
```

Here's the full example

```js
$('.fltsqrs').click(function() {
  $('.fltsqrs').removeClass("fltsqrs2");
  $(this).toggleClass("fltsqrs2");
});
```

```css
.fltsqrs {
  float: left;
  height: 175px;
  width: 185px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.fltsqrs2 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fltsqrs" id="fltsqrs1">
  <img src="../images/cash flow.png" alt=" ">
  <p>Treasury Services</p>
</div>
<div class="fltsqrs" id="fltsqrs2">
  <img src="../images/taxes2.png">
  <p>Taxes</p>
</div>
<div class="fltsqrs">
  <img src="../images/Team.png" alt=" ">
  <p>Bookkeeping</p>
</div>
<div class="fltsqrs">
  <img src="../images/strategy.png" alt=" ">
  <p>Planning</p>
</div>
<div class="fltsqrs">
  <img src="../images/1449867816_1.png" alt=" ">
  <p>HR Services</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your code will "toggle" whether or not each element is in the `fltsqrs2` class. This means that if those elements do not belong to that class, it adds `fltsqrs2` to their class attribute list. If the element already belongs to that class, then it is removed from their class attribute list. This is close to what you want.

The problem is that the original class, `fltsqrs`, is not toggled - i.e. your element always has class `fltsqrs` and is subject to the corresponding CSS.

In short **you need to toggle both classes**. Just try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fltsqrs').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("fltsqrs fltsqrs2");
    });
});
```